# Linked Data Source set as "Joined" not displaying data

Tags: joined-view, dataview, datasource, linked

I have created a "Linked Data Source" and set the type as "Joined".

When I display this "Linked Data source", I am able to see the rows and columns but no data is displayed within it. However, if I am in a particular row, I'm able to view the row data on the "Data Source Details" section on the right hand pane. See Image below

[image]

Just that the data is not displayed in the web part,how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Got it working following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iahtFLEncu8